# If $\frac{ay-bx}{p}=\frac{cx-az}{q}=\frac{bz-cy}{r} $

Tags: proof-verification, ratio

If $$\frac{ay-bx}{p}=\frac{cx-az}{q}=\frac{bz-cy}{r}$$, prove that :
$$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}$$

My solution,
$$\frac{c(ay-bx)}{cp}=\frac{b(cx-az)}{bq}=\frac{a(bz-cy)}{ar}$$.
Now, I could not get enough idea to continue from herr.

Comment: Assume ratios to be $k$ and then simplify

Comment: #Archis, assuming each ratio as $k$ and simplifying all three ratios, it becomes a bit lengthy....

Comment: What are $a,b,c,p,q,r,x,y,z$ supposed to be?

Comment: #Arnaud, I could not understand what you are asking about?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser, he means, are they reals, natural numbers, complex numbers, etc

Comment: Exactly what @vrugtehage said. l I have an idea for an easy proof but it fails if a certain expression is zero, so if I knew for example that all numbers are positive it would be ok.

Comment: Not true. Take $a=-1,b=1,c=1,p=1,q=1,r=2,x=1,y=2,z=-4$.

Comment: You can choose $a,b,c,x,y,z$ at random and make $p,q,r$ so that the ratios are the same

Comment: @vrugtehagel&Arnaud, I guess they are natural numbers..

Comment: Then the identity $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{\alpha'}{\beta'}=\frac{\alpha+\alpha'}{\beta+\beta'}$ could be useful.

Comment: @Arnaud, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser, What is the source of the problem?

Comment: @Lab, I got this question in Mathematics Practice Book, under 'Challenging Exercises On Ratio and Proportion'

Comment: @Lab, But why are you asking about it?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser, Trying figure  out the nature of $a,b,c; p,q,r$

Comment: @Lab, You have provided an answer but I could not understand your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last equation, call the ratio $k$, so that
$$\left\{\begin{array}{}c(ay-bx)& = & kcp\\ b(cx-az) & = & kbq\\ a(bz-cy) & = & kar\end{array}\right.$$
Taking the sum of all these equations yields :
$$acy-bcx+bcx-abz+abz-acy=k(cp+bq+ar).$$The left-hand side is $0$, and $(cp+bq+ar)$ is positive, thus $k=0$. It follows that
$$ay-bx=cx-az=bz-cy=0,$$and thus
$$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}.$$

Comment: Why $$cp+bq+ar > 0?$$

Comment: It was said in the comments that all numbers involved are natural numbers, in particular positive (the question wouldn't make sense if they were zero).

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{ay-bx}p=\frac{\dfrac yb-\dfrac xa}{abp}$$

If $\dfrac yb=\dfrac xa,\dfrac{ay-bx}p=0$

So, each of the given ratio has to be zero

Comment: This is no proof. You're using the thing you had to prove to show that the ratio's are $0$.

Comment: @Lab, could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @vrugtehagel, I've established that we need another condition for the proposition to be true.